# Rule not redirecting .co.uk to .com

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying to get my site, when a visitor goes to .co.uk to be automatically redirected to .com. As well as if they go to domain.com to be taken to www.domain.com

I have the code below in my httpd.conf. It appears to be working with `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` but not `domain.co.uk` or `www.domain.co.uk` to `www.domain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /      
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` questions are equally valid on SO and SF, you're probably better off sticking with it here.

Comment: What is the point of `RewriteBase /` ? I think that the "base" is `/` by default. Tell me if I'm wrong but this directive is useless.

Comment: Please, sentences do not end in commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rewrite rules are in an htaccess file, this should work. If they are in a vhost file (or the Apache httpd.conf itself) try to remove the `/`.

And try to always be case sensitive (get used to because most of languages are case sensitive it's a good habit to take):

---

### If in a `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

---

### If in a `vhost` or  `httpd.conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```

And please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Many thanks, removing the `RewriteBase /` and also the `^` from before domain.co.uk made it work perfectly. I did however still have to keep the / before $1 otherwise it missed the first / from a deep link redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of HTTP_HOST case-sensitive?  The [RewriteCond documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) always lists it as HTTP_HOST, not http_host.  The NC flag won't help with that, since it applies to the string values, not variable names.

Comment: tried changing to 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]` 

but no luck